# In nest.js, how to validate function parameters not form request call

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, nestjs

I have a usecase function, that can be called from other handlers, controllers, services etc.
I would like to validate the parameters of this function.
I was told that class-validation using validation decorators are valid only for parameters that comes from request, that goes through pipes.

The function is like below

```
function getTransactionInfo(
  transactionType: TransactionType,
  user: UserInfoDto,
  fromCurrencyCode?: CurrencyCode,
  toCurrencyCode?: CurrencyCode,
){}
```

TransactionType is an enum with ['deposit', 'withdrawal'].

What I want to validate is

- transactionType, user is always required
- if transactionType is deposit, -> fromCurrencyCode is required
  if transactionType is withdrawal, -> toCurrencyCode is required

I tried @ValidateIf, @Validation, @ValidatorConstraint
but seems to not work. I think this is because that as I mentioned, this is not a request and this function does not go through pipes (Not sure if this is really the reason)

The only validation method I know so far is using DTOs with validation decorators. I'm not sure how to validate normal function parameters.

Comment: You can validate the function params inside the function body using class validator.